# How to retrieve gmail using php?

Tags: php, gmail

I have activated IMAP in my gmail account[image]

I have activated IMAP in php as well

Then I use that php snippet:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'conventionxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'yyyyyyyy';

// try to connect 
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

I got error:

$ php gmail.php

> PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

I use correct login and password. Any idea ?

I tried on Linux and got

> PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /google.php on
>   line 8 Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server:
>   [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser:
>   https://support.google.com/mail/accoPHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying
>   PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser:
>   https://support.google.com/mail/acco (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT]
>   Please log in via your web browser:
>   https://support.google.com/mail/acco (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Just checked, works for me.

Comment: If you are not trying this on your development environment, but some shared hosting service provider your requests might come in to google from anywhere around the world. Chances are google blocks such attempts then to protect your account. You should receive a notification about such incident from them.

Comment: aside from being blacklisted by google, the only other things that i can think of are firewall, and incompatible ssl, being blocked by firewall, and your host not allowing imap stuff. try changing hostname to **"{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";** and updating your ssl library.

Comment: I use that on my WIn7